# Add carriage return to a string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a long string.

```
string s1 = "'99024','99050','99070','99143','99173','99191','99201','99202','99203','99204','99211','99212','99213','99214','99215','99217','99218','99219','99221','99222','99231','99232','99238','99239','99356','99357','99371','99374','99381','99382','99383','99384','99385','99386','99391','99392'";
```

I want

```
string s2 = 
            "'99024',
             '99050',
             '99070',
             '99143',
             '99173',
             '99191',
             '99201',
             '99202',....";
```

In other words. Maybe it likes:

```
string s2 = "'99024',"+'\n'+"'99050',"+'\n'+"'99070',"+'\n'+"'99143',"+'\n'+.....;
```

I need a concise code. Maybe LINQ. Thanks.

Comment: @user1108948  technically, what you want a "newline"  not "carriage return"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
string s2 = s1.Replace(",", ",\n");
```

Comment: You'll probably want s1.Replace(",", ",\n").TrimEnd(',', '\n'); to remove the trailing pair.

Comment: I know, just to be fast, post without testing :)

Comment: @blowdart You assume their's a trailing comma.  There isn't.

Comment: @L.B Actually my VM with visual studio is being mean and needed to be restarted, so I couldn't test it quickly.

Comment: Just in case he adds one :) Certainly does no harm.

Comment: @blowdart You're recreating a new string...and you're also assuming that the OP wouldn't ever *want* a trailing comma/newline.  If he has a trailing comma/space and needs it removed, he can add the code, but since neither was in the specs it's not appropriate in my eyes to add it.

Comment: @L.B You assume he's writing to a file.  You can't know that for sure.  He could be printing to the Console, or only dealing with the strings in memory.  The OP used `\n`, not Environment.NewLine, so there would need to be some compelling reason to change it, which isn't there.

Comment: @Servy I think, an answer that would fit to a *tweet* and known by 99.99% of .Net developers should be as general as possible (think mono & unix).

Comment: To paraphrase Eric Lippert, add the generality when there is a need for it.  Code is written to meet a specific business need and it is not worthwhile to write everything for the general case until there is a need to do so.  If the code is only used in a context in which the environment newline is irreverent, there is no need to use it, or to spend time looking for it everywhere and changing it.  In the same manor, I wouldn't replace a use of `Environment.NewLine` with `\n` without a compelling reason.

Answer (score 44):

```
string s2 = s1.Replace(",", "," + Environment.NewLine);
```

---

Also, just from a performance perspective, here's how the three current solutions I've seen stack up over 100k iterations:

```
ReplaceWithConstant           - Ms: 328, Ticks: 810908
ReplaceWithEnvironmentNewLine - Ms: 310, Ticks: 766955 
SplitJoin                     - Ms: 483, Ticks: 1192545
```

*ReplaceWithConstant*:

```
string s2 = s1.Replace(",", ",\n");
```

*ReplaceWithEnvironmentNewLine*:

```
string s2 = s1.Replace(",", "," + Environment.NewLine);
```

*SplitJoin*:

```
string s2 = String.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, s1.Split(','));
```

*ReplaceWithEnvironmentNewLine* and *ReplaceWithConstant* are within the margin of error of each other, so there's functionally no difference.

Using `Environment.NewLine` should be preferred over `"\n"` for the sake readability and consistency similar to using `String.Empty` instead of `""`.

Comment: @L.B I usually post then test since unfortunately response time is critical. Caught the error in LinqPad a few seconds after posting.

Comment: See my comment in other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string s2 = s1.Replace(",", ",\n") + ",....";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
string s2 = String.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, s1.Split(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment.NewLine should be used as Dan Rigby said but there is one problem with the String.Empty. It will remain always empty no matter if it is read before or after it reads. I had a problem in my project yesterday with that. I removed it and it worked the way it was supposed to. It's better to declare the variable and then call it when it's needed. String.Empty will always keep it empty unless the variable needs to be initialized which only then should you use String.Empty. Thought I would throw this tid-bit out for everyone as I've experienced it.

Answer (score 0):

string s2 = s1.Replace(",", ",\r\n");

Comment: This answer already exists and you're about 5 years too late. Why the answer to such an old question that doesn't add anything new?

Comment: I like this reply, because it points out that, when adding NewLine to a Windows.Forms textbox, you need to use "\r\n" instead of just "\n", thus i have added +1

Answer (score 0):

I propose use `StringBuilder`

```
string s1 = "'99024','99050','99070','99143','99173','99191','99201','99202','99203','99204','99211','99212','99213','99214','99215','99217','99218','99219','99221','99222','99231','99232','99238','99239','99356','99357','99371','99374','99381','99382','99383','99384','99385','99386','99391','99392'";

var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();           

foreach (var s in s1.Split(','))
{
    stringBuilder.Append(s).Append(",").AppendLine();
}
Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder);
```